# How to convert depth or/and point cloud data (.dat file) to OpenCV Mat object using c++?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing, point-clouds

I have a camera TI opt 8241 with resolution 320 x 240. I get a .dat file which consists of the depth and intensity values in as `(z,I)` and point cloud data as `(x,y,z,I)`.

[Download Depth and Intensity data](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=74822597666874550081)

[Download Point cloud data](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=04158296091069283701)

I need to display this data as an `image(Mat object)` in OpenCv using c++. How can I do that?
In Matlab I could display it by using following program

```
fileID= fopen('DepthFrameData.dat','r');

A1=fscanf(fileID,'%f ; %f \n',[2 76800]);

mat = vec2mat(A1(1,:),320);
```

Comment: could you link to a file .dat that we can download and use for testing?

Comment: @Miki I have added the .dat file for your reference.